# Cannot setText inside a Fragment

Tags: android, kotlin, fragment, gettext, settext

I have a simple fragment that has  **EditText**, **Button**, **TextView** . A simple string will be taken from the user and the **TextView** will be updated when the **Button** is clicked.
But it is not working for me, my **TextView** disappears somehow. But if I don't take the string from the user and pre-define it, the **TextView** does change.

My code,

```
class First_Fragment : Fragment() {


override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_first_, container, false)
}

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)


    val text=editTextNumber.text.toString()    //user input

    button.setOnClickListener {

        textView.text=text

    }

}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By capturing `editTextNumber.text.toString()` during `onViewCreated`, you are retrieving the text in the `EditText` in `onViewCreated`, which is empty.

So you should be retrieving the value when the button is clicked as you mentioned.